# If any input field value entered zero then disable else enable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to implement code in that if any of input value entered is zero then disable button otherwise enable. Its working fine when input value entered is zero but after I entered value other then zero it still disabled not enabling I am using counter and I have total nearly 40 text field to check so I am using input type with each statement.

following is fiddle which is I am implemented.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ash3317/1d0da3hu/6/

Comment: Do you want to disable button when all input fields are 0 or one field is 0 ?

Comment: If one of the input value is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `count value` every time ,because you want to check that value is the statement of having 0 value or not.Put it that setting value in `.change()` function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input').change(function()  {
      var count = 0;
      $("input").each(function() {           
         if($(this).val() == "0")
         {
          count = 1;
         }
       });          

       if(count == 0)
            {

          $("#submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled","disabled");

            }
        else
            {
          $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled","disabled");                          
            }
      });
   });
```

Comment: check here @Ash3317

Comment: Hello David your code works well if value I entered 0 but whenever I enter 00, 000 it get enabled.

Comment: use `parseInt()` eg . parseInt($(this).val())

Comment: Thanks David You are the Men bro,Saved my day.:) Here the jsfiddle working link https://jsfiddle.net/ash3317/1d0da3hu/50/

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(
           function() {


          $('input').change(function()  {
           
          // $("input").each(function() {

            if($(this).val()==0)
            {
               $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled","disabled");
            console.log("Disable");
            }
           else{
                    $("#submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
             console.log("Enable");
           }
          

           //  });
           

           });
              });
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = 'number' class="inputBox" >
<input type = 'number' class="inputBox" >
<input type = 'number' class="inputBox" >
<input type = 'number' class="inputBox" >
<input type = 'number' class="inputBox" >
<input type = 'number' class="inputBox" >
<input type = 'number' class="inputBox" >
<input type = 'number' class="inputBox" >
        <button id="submitBtn" >Submit</button>
```

Comment: Hello sarika your logic is same as my code but your code doesn't work for multiple input field .

Comment: have you tried your own code ? Button isn't enable after first time write zero in the input box. also it will not work for multiple input fields.

Comment: Yeah Bhavin I tried my own code its working only first time when value entered zero but when i edited value its not working

Comment: Please check it once it is work for multiple text-box...

Answer (score 0):

Pure HTML version. It won't put a disabled attribute on the button but it will throw a native error if you try to submit the form if any input has a value less than 1. Good to put that min property on there in any case.

```
<form>
<input type="number" min="1"/>
  <input type="number" min="1"/>
  <input type="number" min="1"/>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This works on multiple fields as well

```js
(function() {
    $('form > input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form > input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 0) {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})()

/* instead of form we can use the IDs of certain fields only. In case not all fields are mandatory */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    Enter number<br />
    <input type="number" id="user_input" name="number" /><br />
    <input type="number" id="user_input2" name="number" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working...

Comment: really? what's happening?

Comment: For any value button always disable.

Comment: I don't know if you have read the problem statement properly. Here what it says: I am trying to implement code in that "IF ANY" of input value entered is zero then disable button otherwise enable.

Comment: hello akash your code doesn't work for my fiddle it  disable button if I entered any value.:(

Comment: @Ash3317 check the code snippet above. If any of the input field have value "0" then the button will be disabled. As you have written in the problem statement

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, you have all of your inputs of type `number`. When first `onchange` event happens, it evaluates all of the inputs. Even if some the inputs do not have values, because they are of type `number`, their default value is 0. And your code is working at first because you are not checking inputs until the first `onchange` event fires.

You can check this if you enter all input fields with a non-zero value, then your button should be enabled. If you remove a value from one of them, it should be disabled again.

Comment: Thanks eminlala I was also thinking its beacuse of type number but I don't know exactly input type = "number" having default value zero.

Answer (score 0):

It working for me :
HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-input" id="input" >
<button id="fbtn">Submit</button>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#input').on('keyup',function(){
        var val = $('#input').val();
        if (val == 0) {
            $("#fbtn").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }else{
            $("#fbtn").removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
        }
    });
</script>
```

You should add validation for input field. i mean accept only number etc.